# How to connect to cql3 using Hector api

Tags: cassandra

I have created a table as below using cql 3 (using Cassandra 1.1.12)

```
Create table User  (
   ... userid varchar,
   ... password varchar,
   ... email varchar,
   ... gender varchar,
   ... fullName varchar,
   ... dateOfBirth varchar,
   ... bloodGroup varchar,
   ... ethnicity varchar,
   ... PRIMARY KEY (userid)
   ... );
```

But using hector api, I am not able to insert data in the column family.

```
      Mutator<String> mutator = HFactory.createMutator(emr, ss);
    System.out.println("Inserting");
            mutator.addInsertion(user.getUserID(), USER, HFactory.createStringColumn(FULL_NAME, user.getFullName()))
                    .addInsertion(user.getUserID(), USER, HFactory.createStringColumn(EMAIL, user.getEmail()))
                    .addInsertion(user.getUserID(), USER, HFactory.createStringColumn(DOB, user.getDateOfBirth()))
                    .addInsertion(user.getUserID(), USER, HFactory.createStringColumn(BLOOD_GROUP, user.getBloodGroup()))
                     .addInsertion(user.getUserID(), USER, HFactory.createStringColumn(PASSWORD, user.getPassword()))
                      .addInsertion(user.getUserID(), USER, HFactory.createStringColumn(ETHNICITY, user.getEthnicity()))
                    .addInsertion(user.getUserID(), USER, HFactory.createStringColumn(GENDER, user.getGender()));

            mutator.execute();
```

It is giving below error

Exception in thread "main" me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HInvalidRequestException: InvalidRequestException(why:unconfigured columnfamily User)

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why:unconfigured columnfamily User

This exception means you are trying to insert into a CF that hasn't been created. Create the column family `user` and then the above should work.